# pgfplots hides the last column in bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a document in which I need a bar chart like this:

[image: desired chart]

I used `pgfplots` as:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [ybar,
              ymin=0,
              xtick=data,
              xtick pos=left,
              xticklabel interval boundaries,
              nodes near coords,
              nodes near coords style = {anchor=south west,
                                         align=center},
              symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H},
             ]
\addplot [ybar interval] coordinates
         {(A, 5) (B, 7)
          (C, 9) (D, 15)
          (E, 8) (F, 20)
          (G, 16) (H, 13)
         };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but the column `H` disappears:

[image: bad result]

I read somewhere (I can't remember where) that a workaround is to add a column with value 0, so I did so. The problem is, column `I` shouldn't exist in the resulting chart, but it has its label too:

[image]

Is there a way to remove it (keeping the other columns' ones)? Or is there a better way to make `pgfplots` show all the columns?

Comment: It's kind if by definition when you use `ybar interval` that the last column disappears. Any particular reason for using it?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, in my document data on x axis are continous, so I need the bars to touch the near ones. But I'm new to pgfplots and `ybar interval` is just the first (working) way I found to do that, if there is another way to achieve the same result it's good as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}`, or some higher version, you can set `bar width=1`, and the bars will get a width of 1 in axis units. This doesn't work with symbolic coordinates though, so you'll need numeric coordinates and use `xticklabels`. No adjustment of the `nodes  near coords` is necessary in this case.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
             bar width=1, % with compat=1.7 or higher, a unitless number means axis units are used
             ymin=0,
             xtick=data,
             xtick pos=left,
             nodes near coords,
             xticklabels={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H},
             %% if the ticks has to be between columns, the following four lines can be uncommented
             %tickwidth=0,
             %extra x ticks={-0.5,0.5,...,8.5},
             %extra x tick labels={},
             %extra x tick style={tickwidth=0.15cm}
             ]

% you can use "coordinates {(1,5)(2,7) ...}" instead of "table[.." if you prefer that
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex, y index=0,row sep=\\] {5\\7\\9\\15\\8\\20\\16\\13\\};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example works with many columns, but it breaks if they are diminished in number (left and right space reduces or disappears and lateral columns look like they are partially cut out). Probably my fault, but I can't figure out where is the problem.

Comment: @Ntakwetet The limits on the x-axis. Try adding `enlarge x limits={abs=0.75}`.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty trick solution. It works if in `axis` options is not used `clip=false`:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    ybar,
    ymin=0, ymax=25,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel interval boundaries,
    enlarge x limits=.05,
    symbolic x coords = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={%
        xshift=1.25*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/bar width},
        anchor=south, align=center},
    ]
\addplot[ybar interval,
        draw=black, fill=gray!10] 
        coordinates{  (A, 5) (B, 7) (C, 9) (D,15)
                      (E, 8) (F,20) (G,16) (H,13)
                      (I,-1) % dummy data, clip=false is prohibited
                    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]